# What is the closest thing to the C# internal modified that you can get in Java?

Tags: java, .net, jar, obfuscation, access-modifiers

.NET has a package internal scope that makes a type visible to a module (.dll file), what is the closest equivalent in Java? The default visibility relates to a package name only and does not care about how the classes are bundled.

I know nothing better exists in the Java language itself, but is there tooling for simulating this that plays nice with builds systems and IDE:s? For example, is there an obfuscation tool that hides away all classes annotated with a specific annotation, and tooling supported by common Java IDE:s to ensure that such classes are not used by anything outside of its module?

Comment: You need to obfuscate your classes to your own package?

Comment: @Igor, I need to ensure that they are not accessible from outside the produced jar file, using an obfuscation tool that rewrites the annotated classes might be one way of doing that, although I would prefer them not to be renamed etc.

Comment: Accessible do you mean to not be able to instantiate/use the classes? Or not to be able to unpack the jar and get them?

Comment: @Igor, simply not being able to reference/use them from other classes outside of that compiled .jar. I do not need obfuscation as such, I only mentioned it as one possible approach to this, maybe renaming these classes to something containing special characters to make them inaccessible from normal Java code.

Comment: In my opinion, "package access" classes—that is, top-level classes declared without the `public` modifier—serve the same function.  They are only visible to classes in the same package.

Comment: As commented by @VGR, use the default package-private access, that is, declaring classes and/or methods without any modifier. In this case, only calls from inside the same package will be able to access them. Never from outside that package or jar.

Comment: 1) I want to access the types from other packages (but the same jar) 2) classes with package private access are still visible from outside the jar, if you pretend to be in the same package (though this can be prevented, I know)

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have something like that yet.

You can put these classes in a package named "internal" and exclude it from javadoc.